# Add attribute to RadioButtonList input for JQuery Validation

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-validate

How can I add `required` to one of the input fields which I believe is needed to enable `JQuery Valiadation` on a radio button group.

I can add `required` to the `RadioButtonList` control by doing the following

`rbSeverity.Attributes.Add("required","");`

But how can this attribute be added to one of the inputs that is generated from the `<asp:ListItem>` control?

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbSeverity" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow"
                                runat="server" >
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $('#<%= rbSeverity.ClientID %> input').attr('required', '');
});
```

The above code will insert all the `required` attribute to all the input inside the radio button list.